# python: Returning mininum in numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

I have an array [test] of type numpy.ndarray:

```
[' -0.1 ' ' -0.4 ' ' -0.6 ' ' -0.2 ' ' -3.4 ' ' 0.0 ' ' -1.9 ' ' -1.2 ' ' -0.5 ']
```

and want to find the minimum value.

If I do `print min(test)` the value returned is -0.1 which is not the minimum (i.e. -3.4)

How do I correctly return the minimum value.

Comment: Convert to float values?

Comment: It looks like the values in your array are strings, not numbers.  Take a look at `test.dtype`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a list of strings too... the min gives -0.1 for strings and -3.4 for floats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert first:

```
test.astype(float).min()
```